# Can I send richly-formatted Slack messages as a Bot and not as a Webhook?

Tags: python, slack-api, slack

I started writing a Slack bot in Python and came to a halt when I couldn't find a way to send richly-formatted messages using the either of the two methods:

```
sc.rtm_send_message("channel_name", my_message)

sc.api_call("chat.postMessage", channel="channel_name", text=my_message, username="username", icon_url="icon_url")
```

where `my_message = json.dumps({'attachments': [{...}]})`

I now know that I can do this using the webhook approach but is it possible with the above method?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by richly formatted messages?

Comment: Loads of good information can be found [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting) and you can try it out in the browser [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out where I was going wrong.

I was passing my message to the wrong argument in the `sc.api_call` method.

I should've been passing it to `sc.api_call(`**`attachments=`**`...)` argument, not the `text` argument.

Answer (score 5):

Both API (method chat.postMessage) and incoming webhook offer the same options for formatting your messages including markup and attachments.

Hint: if you want to use markup in your attachments, make sure to add the field "mrkdwn_in" and name the field your want to use it in or it will be ignored by Slack.

Example:

```
{
    "attachments": [
        {
            "title": "Title",
            "pretext": "Pretext _supports_ mrkdwn",
            "text": "Testing *right now!*",
            "mrkdwn_in": ["text", "pretext"]
        }
    ]
}
```

See [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting) for full documentation.